# Account transfer to another region

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any limitations for account transfer from one region to another? I mean for example, from Euro West to Euro East or from NA to Euro West, etc. I mean in limitations any limitation, for example, the number of times that one account can be transferred or the time between two transfers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, but just keep in mind that each transfer costs 2600 RP each and it can't be refunded. Also keep in mind: If you're in NA, transfer to EUW, then transfer back to NA, you will have to spend 5200 RP.

Answer (score 1):

**Things that will transfer:**

- Summoner Level Champions and skins (ward skins too)
- Runes Rune pages
- Summoner icons IP and XP boosts
- IP balance Remaining RP (after the
  cost of the transfer)
- Hidden MMR value Statistics: games played,
  takedowns, wins, etc
- Loading screen borders
- Your Placement Matches
- Item Sets *
- Previous redeemed referrals Summoner name and username**

Source: https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/26112905-Account-Transfer-FAQ#affect

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question. OP asks whether there are limitations to transferring regions, not what things are transferred.